# How to remove files related to running a program that wasn't installed as a package

Tags: uninstall

I run Blender 2.77a from within the folder created when the .tar.bz2 was extracted. I just right-clicked on the downloaded .tar.bz2, selected 'Extract here', and then moved the resulting folder to the Desktop for easier access. I have had a few small but strange problems with it lately, and thought maybe removing it and reinstalling it would help.

It wasn't installed as a package, so how do I find and remove its related files to start fresh?

Actually, I never removed the previous version, Blender 2.76b. I'm pretty naive about all this stuff and it is occurring to me now maybe that was a bad idea. I looked up Blender in the Software Center and when it showed it was already installed I remembered that little detail that I'd left it on the system. I clicked on Remove there in the Software Center, and opened Blender 2.77a to test whether this helped with the file system problem I was having. Nope.

So, maybe all files related to running blender need to be removed from the system. How do you do that when a program wasn't installed as a package?

Comment: Please describe how exactly you installed it, what commands did you run etc.

Comment: @ByteCommander I clarified a bit with an edit. All it was was rightclick > select 'Extract here' > move created folder.

Comment: Um, I saw about sudo apt-get autoremove, and running that caused a lot of activity. One thing removed was `blender-data (2.76.b+dfsg0-3build1)`.  But there were a lot of other things as i completely forget about system maintenance.

Comment: If you "installed" something only by extracting an archive somewhere without running any install scripts or `make` commands, I guess deleting that directory (and maybe places the app stored config and user data, if applying) should be enough.

Comment: I found the blender folder in the .config folder of home, after going to View in the menu bar and clicking Show Hidden Files. It has subfolders for several versions, and the one for 2.77 has nothing that looks like it could have any effect at all. So i am leaving it. Efforts to address the issue by updating Nvidia drivers using the ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa are so far not working.